# Why does the modulus operator work in a .bat file but not in a .awk script

Tags: windows, modulo, quoting

`File1.bat` contains

```
gawk "BEGIN {print 5%%3}"
```

and runs with output 2 (ran at Windows cmd prompt as: `File1`)

`File2.awk` contains:

```
"BEGIN {print 5%%3}"
```

but hangs (when running at Windows cmd prompt as: `gawk -f File2.awk`)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is represented by % thus on the command line or in a script input the correct method would be

`{print 5%3}`

so in the cmd console you would enter (*using single or double quotes will depend on source compilation.*) and may not even be needed at all, if the command is very simple and does not contain system command symbols such as `>` or `&` which do require wrapping as a string literal. For details
see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/DOS-Quoting.html

```
gawk "BEGIN {print 5%3}"
```

And thus `BEGIN {print 5%3}` is all that is needed for the File2.awk input.

However when using a batch.cmd to run the command line we need to "double escape" the `%percent%` use of that variables symbol by adding another, in effect its treated like *`%nothing/nul%`*.

so within a File1.bat the necessarily command becomes "Double quotes" for Windows passing the string to gawk and batch iteration combining the %% as one % since there is no variable between them.

```
gawk "BEGIN {print 5%%3}"
```

Comment: @K J:  "BEGIN {print 5%3}" in File2.awk doesn't work.

Comment: @K J: In Windows 10, neither a single (') nor a double (")  quote is needed before the BEGIN keyword or after the braces. Thx.